# How to hint Sorbet with const_get and dynamic parent class?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sorbet

How can I allow a class's parent to be dynamically defined and pass Sorbet type checking?

For example:

```rb
class A; end

class B < Object.const_get("A"); end
```

This is part of a Rails gem that requires configuring the base class of a model, similar to [Devise configuring a parent controller class](https://github.com/heartcombo/devise/blob/5d5636f03ac19e8188d99c044d4b5e90124313af/app/controllers/devise_controller.rb#L4).

When running this, `srb tc` returns the error: `Superclasses must only contain constant literals https://srb.help/4002`

Alternatively, I have tried hinting:

```rb
class A; end

class B < T.let(Object.const_get("A"), A); end
```

...which results in type-checking errors like `Method some_method does not exist on T.class_of(B) https://srb.help/7003`, and `srb rbi hidden-definitions` throws this error:

```
ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/sorbet-runtime-0.5.6371/lib/types/private/casts.rb:23:in `cast': T.let: Expected type A, got type Class with value A (TypeError)
```

Comment: If the parent class is only known at runtime then you're going to have issues doing static type checking. I guess you could use `class B < T.let(Object.const_get("A"), T.class_of(Object.const_get("A"))); end`.

Comment: I do know that `A` will inherit from some superclass. For example, in Devise I know that `Devise.parent_controller` will always inherit from `ActionController::Base`.